# Can't display image I uploaded in PHP

Tags: php, html, file

I'm trying to upload an image and display after uploading, the upload part works fine but image can't display.
Any answers?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo <<<_END

            <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="fupload" size="100000" accept="image/*">
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
            </form>
_END;

        if($_FILES){
            $name = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($name = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'], $name);
            echo "<br><img src='$name'>";
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Browser:
[Image can't display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwgXQ.png)

Comment: add   echo "<H2>final name=$name<H2>" before <img...> and see what's happens, observe the final name, It is a public valid path ?

Comment: does the file contain special characters? Try with a simple file name: monimage.jpg (without spaces, comma, apostrophe, etc ...)

Comment: try do display the result of move command : $retAction=move_uploaded....;  echo "retAction is ".$retAction?'true':'false'

Comment: I found that the file I uploaded was "tg.png" and the path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\tmp\php2505.tmp". My moved_upload_file($name = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'], $name) ; returns true but my image still doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, the problem is move_upload ($name=xxxx, $name), it means you assign to $name the tmp source !

here is a working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

       <form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="fupload" size="100000" accept="image/*">
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
       </form>

       <?php if($_FILES)
        {
            $source=$_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
            $target1 = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($source,$target1);
       ?>

       <br>
       source=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($source);?>
       <br>
       target=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($target1);?>  
       <img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($target1);?>"

       <?php
        } // if $_FILES 
       ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, following comment, it seems $name point To à path not accessible for external user. Try a link like this $name="c:\path  To your base path\www\et.png"

Edit: supposing you have a existing www folder , where you find  your index.php. It may be called public.